# Need to diff two text files in linux with some patterns in filelines

Tags: shell, scripting

File A contains

```
Test-1.2-3
Test1-2.2-3
Test2-4.2-3
```

File B contains

```
Test1
```

Expected output should be

```
Test-1.2-3
Test2-4.2-3
```

`diff A B` doesn't work as expected.
Kindly let me know if any solutions here.

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: I've been trying for **years** to get it into the head of my boss that *one* special example case is a really poor way to specify a *pattern*....

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep`:

`grep -vf B A`

> ```
>   -f FILE, --file=FILE
>           Obtain patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty  file
>           contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.
>
>   -v, --invert-match
>           Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
> ```

**Edit:**

Optionally, you may want to use the `-w` option if you want a more precise match on "words" only which seems to be your case from your example since your match is followed by '-'. As DevSolar points out, you may also want to use the `-F` option to prevent input patterns from your file `B` to be interpreted as regular expressions.

`grep -vFwf B A`

> ```
>   -w, --word-regexp
>           Select only those  lines  containing  matches  that  form  whole
>           words.   The  test is that the matching substring must either be
>           at the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a  non-word
>           constituent  character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end
>           of the line or followed by  a  non-word  constituent  character.
>           Word-constituent   characters   are  letters,  digits,  and  the
>           underscore.
>   -F, --fixed-strings
>           Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings (rather than regular
>           expressions), separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.
> ```

Comment: Potentially adding `-F`, to use lines from file B as fixed strings instead of interpreting them as patterns.

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Julien Lopez's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36573284/45375):

**If you want to ensure that lines from File B only match at the *beginning* of lines from File A**, you can *prepend `^` to each line from file B*, using `sed`:

```
grep -vf <(sed 's/^/^/' fileB) fileA
```

`grep`, which by default interprets its search strings as [BREs (basic regular expressions)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03), then interprets the `^` as the beginning-of-line anchor.

If the lines in File B may contain characters that are regex *metacharacters* (such as `^`, `*`,`?`, ...) but should be treated as *literals*, you must *escape* them first:

```
grep -vf <(sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g; s/^/^/' fileB) fileA
```

<sup>An explanation of this grim-looking - but generically robust - `sed` command can be found in this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29613573/45375) of mine.</sup>

Note:

- Assumes `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh` due to use of `<(...)`, a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution), which makes the output from `sed` act as if it were provided via a file.
- `sed` command `s/^/^/` looks like it won't do anything, but the first `^`, in the *regex* part of the call, is the beginning-of-line anchor<sup>[1]</sup>
  , whereas the second `^`, in the substitution part of the call, is a *literal* to place at the beginning of the line (which will later itself be interpreted as the beginning-of-line anchor in the context of `grep`).

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, to `sed` it is the beginning-of-*pattern-space* anchor, because it is possible to read multiple lines at once with `sed`, in which case `^` refers to the beginning of the pattern space (input buffer) *as a whole*, not to individual lines.</sup>

Comment: A nice and compact way to modify the input for `grep`, neat! I always found odd that there are so few options in `grep` for matching control, it would be nice to have more than `-w` and `-x` to use with `-f`.